# How to commit & push selected files but not all in Git

Tags: git, push, commit, git-merge, smartgit

I have a git repo with two branches: `develop` and `master`. I work mostly at `develop` and when files are ready (sometimes not so sticky to this affirmation) I merge them to `master` branch to put them on production. Take a look to this pic:

[image]

All that files comes from `develop` branch and was merged but I only want to commit and push `RepresentativeRestController.php` but any time I do right click => commit all of them are included on the commit. How I get rid, temporary since they will be added later, of the ones I don't want to be included on the commit? I use Smartgit as a GUI client for Bitbucket repository. Any advice?

Comment: Judging by the commit message it seems that you want to merge the commits from the develop branch onto the master branch. The merge operation should create a new commit in the master branch, that's probably why the app does not let you to
However if you say it lets you unstage some files it can not be a "merge commit"

Are you trying to "merge" some uncommited files from develop to master?  That's not how a merge should be performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a commit, all the *staged* file are included in the commit. If you wish to exclude certain files from a commit, unstage those files first.

I'm not sure how to do that with the Git UI you are using, but there should be a screen or something to manage which files with changes are staged and which aren't.

Comment: Thx, all that I need to know was "unstage" I wasn't clear about it. I have tested from the GUI and it works

Answer (score 4):

Use terminal to commit selected file :
like: you have 100 files (10 type)

> `git add *.*` all file
>
> `git add *.jpg` all jpg file
>
> `$ git add .`   # add to index only files created/modified and not those deleted
>
> `$ git add -u`  # add to index only files deleted/modified and not those created

you can use [source tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) for all git work.