# How can I push changes to a github repository as a different user?

Tags: git, github

I forked a git repo on github as natereed (nate@natereed.com).

I cloned the repo locally and issued the following commands to configure the identity used to push changes:

```
git config user.name "natereed"
git config user.email "nate@natereed.com"
```

I tried to push to the origin, but I get a 403 (Unauthorized):

```
USAU9900:ExData_Plotting1 reedn$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to natereed/ExData_Plotting1.git denied to reedndnb.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/natereed/ExData_Plotting1/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

It seems to still be using a different identity (reedndbn). How can I force it (git/ssh) to use the username ("natereed") that I configured above and used to clone the repo?

Here is my .git/config:

```
USAU9900:ExData_Plotting1 reedn$ more .git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/natereed/ExData_Plotting1
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
        name = natereed
        email = nate@natereed.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *.git/config* you have this:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/natereed/ExData_Plotting1
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

So you cloned this using the *https* protocol and you apparently already set up a github association for *https* using *reedndbn* . When I connect to github via https, I am prompted for a user and a password.

So change `url = https://github.com/natereed/ExData_Plotting1` to 
`https://natereed@github.com/natreeed/ExData_Plotting1.git`. Or if you have a github ssh key association set up for *natereed*, you can use `git@github.com:natereed/ExData_Plotting1.git`.

Alternatively (and I suppose some would say a better way to do) is to change this using the *git remote set-url* command. See [Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)
.

Comment: I don't want to commit changes as reedndnb. The account that owns the repo is user "natereed". The strange thing is that is also the account in my .git/config. That should work but doesn't...

Comment: Thanks for adding your complete config. Under remote origin you are using https, not ssh. So change that to: git@github.com:natereed/ExData_Plotting1.git   On https://github.com/natereed/ExData_Plotting1 under the "clone" section is where you get that ssh url.

Comment: Can you explain why to use ssh and not https for the remote origin? It does make the error go away, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

First Add SHH key in git and create permission for your system

`<Use default path>  $  ssh-keygen -t rsa -C <email id>`

`$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
paste key in git add shh .
then 
 ‘git config --global user.name ”USER_NAME” 
 `‘git config --global user.email “EMAIL_ID”`
[etc..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655063/how-to-commit-push-selected-files-but-not-all-in-git/30663730#30663730)